# python sys.stdin.read not working

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    text = sys.stdin.read().decode('ascii', errors='replace')
    print text
```

When I run it, I enter the text and press enter, but nothing happens and it keeps running forever. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Flush the standard input with `Ctrl+d`
- alternatively use `input()` or `raw_input()`
- check the docs `>>> help(sys.stdin.read)`

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the text, press the `Enter` key, then press `Ctrl + Z`. It will give the correct result.

For more help, please visit this: https://bugs.python.org/issue5505

Comment: Ctrl-Z is Windows-specific. On real computers, try ctrl-D.

Comment: Yes, but Ctrl + Z will work in cmd, I have tested it. Ctrl + D was not working in cmd.